# Optimization level breaks the C code order

Tags: c, gcc, volatile

I have the following 5 lines of code and want the this lines are executed in exact this order with O2 or O3:

```
    PORT->Group[GPIO_PORTB].OUTCLR.reg = (volatile uint32_t) 1 << 9;
    TC3->COUNT16.COUNT.reg =  (volatile uint16_t) 0;
    TC3->COUNT16.CC[0].reg = (volatile uint16_t) vusb_driver->in_data->bitlength;
    SERCOM0->SPI.DATA.reg = (volatile uint32_t) 0x54;
    DMAC->Channel[USB_SEND_SD_DMA_CH].CHCTRLA.reg = (volatile uint8_t) DMAC_CHCTRLA_ENABLE;
```

If I optimize with O2 or O3 the code breaks at line 264 because this line must be executed before line 265:

```
  261:      PORT->Group[GPIO_PORTB].OUTCLR.reg = (volatile uint32_t) 1 << 9;
200001EE   ldr  r1, [pc, #84]        
   263:         TC3->COUNT16.CC[0].reg = (volatile uint16_t) vusb_driver->in_data->bitlength;
200001F0   ldr  r5, [pc, #84]        
   264:         SERCOM0->SPI.DATA.reg = (volatile uint32_t) 0x54;
200001F2   ldr  r4, [pc, #88]        
   265:         DMAC->Channel[USB_SEND_SD_DMA_CH].CHCTRLA.reg = (volatile uint8_t) DMAC_CHCTRLA_ENABLE;
200001F4   ldr  r0, [pc, #88]        
   261:         PORT->Group[GPIO_PORTB].OUTCLR.reg = (volatile uint32_t) 1 << 9;
200001F6   mov.w    r6, #512         
200001FA   str.w    r6, [r1, #148]       
   262:         TC3->COUNT16.COUNT.reg =  (volatile uint16_t) 0;
200001FE   strh r2, [r3, #20]        
   263:         TC3->COUNT16.CC[0].reg = (volatile uint16_t) vusb_driver->in_data->bitlength;
20000200   ldr  r2, [r5]         
20000202   ldr  r2, [r2, #20]        
20000204   ldrh.w   r2, [r2, #72]        
20000208   strh r2, [r3, #28]        
   264:         SERCOM0->SPI.DATA.reg = (volatile uint32_t) 0x54;
2000020A   movs r5, #84      
   265:         DMAC->Channel[USB_SEND_SD_DMA_CH].CHCTRLA.reg = (volatile uint8_t) DMAC_CHCTRLA_ENABLE;
2000020C   movs r2, #2       
   264:         SERCOM0->SPI.DATA.reg = (volatile uint32_t) 0x54;
2000020E   str  r5, [r4, #40]
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Force order of execution of C statements?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19292075/force-order-of-execution-of-c-statements)

Comment: I suppose `-o0` isn't acceptable ?

Comment: Where does the store to `DMAC->Channel[USB_SEND_SD_DMA_CH].CHCTRLA.reg` occur in the above assembly listing? It looks like it has only got as far as storing to `SERCOM0->SPI.DATA.reg` so far.

Answer (score 2):

Your use of `volatile` is incorrect, you should define the destination objects as `volatile` to ensure they are written to exactly in the order of the program.

Comment: The question is how?

Comment: Does the (correct) usage of `volatile` on seemingly independant addresses guarantee the order of execution?

Comment: @makurisan I suppose like this: `SERCOM0->SPI.DATA.reg = (volatile uint32_t) 0x54;` -> `((volatile uint32_t*) SERCOM0)->SPI.DATA.reg = 0x54;`

Comment: @makurisan: Can you post the type definitions?

Comment: @Jabberwocky Thanks this works. ((volatile Sercom *)SERCOM0)

Comment: @chqrlie [This SO article](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14785639/may-accesses-to-volatiles-be-reordered) answers the question I raised in my first comment to your answer.

Answer (score 1):

The compiler is - in the regular case - allowed to reorder instructions if the effect of the execution is the same (this is the ["as-if rule"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15718262/what-exactly-is-the-as-if-rule)). So you must do one of the following:

- Indicate to it that the instructions will have a different effect (e.g. by making the relevant `.reg` variables volatile; or through aliasing of pointers etc.)
- Use some sort of compiler-specific directives to control its behavior.
- Not compile, i.e. generate your machine code in a different manner.

Specifically, if you choose the first option, you must explain - to the compiler and perhaps to yourself, why is it that

> line [264] must be executed before line 265

In what sense "must" it be executed before 265? Who would notice? It's likely that a concrete answer to this question is something you could use to force the desired order of execution.

Comment: _"In what sense "must" it be executed before 265"_: maybe it's some hardware requirement.

Comment: @Jabberwocky: That  wouldn't answer the question. What _is_ the hardware requirement, _exactly_?

Comment: Good question, only the OP knows this as only _he_ knows what hardware his code is running on

Comment: [This SO article](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14785639/may-accesses-to-volatiles-be-reordered) is interesting

Comment: @Jabberwocky; The spi must be set with the data first because 0x54 is the sync field of the Data protocol. After that the configured DMA sent the rest of the transaction.